# Fedora-20 not booting from Live USB stick

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, liveusb

I tried to configure my USB with the image file for the latest Fedora-20 release using Image Writer. When I try to boot the installation from it in my PC the boot-loader is showing up but the load fails with the message:

```
[ 1.73447] nouveau E[ PDISP][000:01:00.0] chid 0 nthd 0x02a4 0x0000000 0x100032a4 0x00000000
```

So, where is the problem? What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a Fedora-specific tool for creating live USB drives - [Fedora Media Writer](https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/download/) (Windows/Mac/Linux). Fedora Media Writer (formerly Fedora Live USB Creator) is a free and open source tool for easily installing live operating systems onto USB flash drives.

#### Features

- Cross-platform (available for Windows, Mac and Linux)
- There is no need to deal with formatting or partitioning your USB flash drive.
- Automatically detects all removable devices
- Supports automatically downloading various Fedora releases
- Persistent storage creation, to save all documents created and modifications made to the system
- Checksum verification
- Not limited to Fedora releases, supports custom images

[image]

Comment: I had a similar problem with OpenSuse - using the custom OS tool worked a treat, and was way-easier than the hack-around I was trying.

Answer (score 2):

checkout this link https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_Live_USB

follow the dd command it worked for me

To write the ISO file directly to the disk, run:

su -c "dd if=/Users/me/Downloads/Fedora-17-x86_64-DVD.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=8M"

Or, if you are running an Ubuntu-based distribution

sudo dd if=/Users/me/Downloads/Fedora-17-x86_64-DVD.iso of=/dev/sdX bs=8M

Comment: What does this do? What is /dev/sdX? Why is this better than the current method? Just giving a command hamstrings your answer. More details will turn this from a cryptic string into a potentially awesome answer.

Comment: edited my answer check now